# Google analytics - reporting analytics from multiple web servers

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

We have devices where each device hosts a web server.
We would like to collect analytics across a majority of these devices.

The Google analytics account setup asks for a single website.
However, since we have multiple devices with a web server, we do not really have a single website to host our application on.
Can we setup Google analytics to aggregate analytics from multiple web servers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

The way I've done it before is to add the host as a custom field within the profile and adding that to the front of every page view. I believe this breaks some minor functionality within the Google Analytics Dashboard however.